# Cannot specify id of a button while echoing ajax through php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to have a button 'Make admin' for each row retrieved from the database. This button should make the specified user an Admin through AJAX. The idea is to make the id of each button equal to the fetched email of the row and assign an onclick ajax for each button. The ajax should send the fethced email which updates the user type column and makes it 'ADMIN'.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        //show all data using <td>
        $email = $row['email'];
        echo "<td><button id=".$row['email'].">Make Admin</button></td>";
        echo "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#$email').click(function(){
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'GET',
                                url: 'makeadmin.php',
                                data: ({email: '".$row['email']."'}),
                                datatype: 'html',
                                success: function(response){                    
                                            $('#makeadmin').html(response);
                                            //alert(response);
                                        },
                                error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    </script>";
}
```

The above code shows the following error in the console:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #admin@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to make something like this
in this line

```
 $('#$email').click(function(){
```

replace with

```
$('#".str_replace(array('@', '.'), array('_','-'), $email)."').click(function(){
```

and do the same for the id for the `<td>`

```
echo "<td><button id=".str_replace(array('@', '.'), array('_','-'), $row['email']).">Make Admin</button></td>";
```

Comment: Your solution worked. Can you please tell me why jquery was not allowing the @ symbol as a part of the selector?

Comment: I googled now about the allowed characters for an html id attribute. Thanks :)

Comment: it's not jQuery related, as Id attribute must begin with a letter.

Answer (score 1):

Like '#' and '.' you cannot you '@' while naming HTML tag id or class. Also quotes are missing for the value of id.

What you can do to fix this:

1. Use a custom HTML tag attribute to store the email address.
2. Assign class to the buttons and bind click event to the class. This will allow you to place the js code in a separate JS file.

So the code should look like below:

**HTML**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        //show all data using <td>
        $email = $row['email'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo "<td><button id='user_".$id."' class='make_admin' email='".$email."'>Make Admin</button></td>";
   }
```

**JS**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('.make_admin').click(function(){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: 'makeadmin.php',
                            data: ({email: $(this).attr('email')}),
                            datatype: 'html',
                            success: function(response){                    
                                        // UI changes
                                        //alert(response);
                                    },
                            error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}
                        });
                    });
                });
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Note that the JS is not in the loop, so it'll not clutter your markup